# Challenge Links for Challenge Series: On-Topic for PPCG?

Tags: discussion

As some of you may already know, there is currently a challenge series called the Advent Challenge series, posted entirely by me (so far).

The purpose of this meta question is to determine whether or not posting a link list would be on-topic for posting to meta.

For example, I would post a brief description of the challenge series and then a list of links for all of the challenges in the series.

An alternative would be to post the link description in the first challenge of the series. The reason I prefer this option is because the alternative would require editing the main post every time I post a new one which requires two challenge "bumps" each day (or however often I post).

So, what would be the best idea?

Comment: Wouldn't a little list at the end of each challenge, linking to all currently-existing challenges suffice? If you only update at maybe day 6, 12, 18, and 24 then it wouldn't spam the front page (or maybe it would..)

Comment: @Riker the problem is as you described, any timeI make an update to keep the link list up to date it will spam the front page with all oft the edits lol

Answer (score 7):

What I've done in the past is to link back to the first instalment from each entry in the series. That way, all the challenges show up in the *Linked* sidebar of the first challenge (and you can get there easily from any other part of the series) and you never need to bump any challenges.

It may be worth pointing this out explicitly near the link, because some users are not aware of the *Linked* sidebar.

Comment: A similar but less elegant option is to maintain a list in your personal profile.